# Same college class: topology

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

This puzzle is toroidal.  That is, every answer that hits the bottom (or right) of the puzzle continues in the same line from the top (respectively left).

[image]

#### Across

**1.** Improvise a dance with extremely unfair YouTuber (4,3)
**2.** Jicama's maybe an emetic? (3,4)
**3.** Put down implement (7)
**4.** Jeannie Zappe became extremely well-regarded; in the end, she evoked idolizing (7)
**5.** *Friends* character's sixth to be chucked out: a duck (Chandler's), in the finale (7)
**6.** Welcome a singer home (5,2)
**9.** Ninety-thou MRI? That's nuts (7)
**12.** Maybe a queen provided some capital (7)
**13.** Hear old Tom losing his head repeatedly for county? (7)
**14.** Sounds like a South African fellow used to make cabinets out of this material (3,4)
**15.** I'm in pursuit of the ultimate in adornment, embodied in a gem of the highest quality (7)
**16.** Overdue put in a contract (7)
**17.** Landed gentry have appetizers (instead of soup) first on the menu (7)
**18.** Defected Soviet Russian premier says goodbye (3,4)
**21.** It's meant for lifting around in a smooth curve! (7)
**24.** Buy "Glad All Over": it's got top spot (7)

#### Down

**3.** Expelled *and* decapitated? Sad (7)
**4.** Levantine city captured by native Egyptian Djer? I choose burial (7)
**5.** Trembling, I've replaced extraterrestrial leader in probe (7)
**6.** Same college class (7)
**7.** Perhaps a knight's heartless devil! (7)
**8.** Holder of logs (one cherry) in confusion (4-3)
**10.** NYC landmark architect sold Met willy-nilly (7)
**11.** Crumpled mail's OK for a Cardinal (7)
**15.** "For a whole month, it's buggy!" "Reboot, and install C." (7)
**16.** Community washed up, put down (7)
**17.** Maintenance for your car to be performed periodically? We at Lug-a-Nut Club *serve*, like… John Donald Budge. (4,3)
**18.** Audiologist's department in a hospital? Good job (1,3,3)
**19.** Periodical picked up, absorbed by man-cave habitue (7)
**20.** Messed-up alligator, with neither a tail nor, ultimately, snout?! (7)
**22.** Before exiting statistical software environment, figure out relationship between an outcome and a predictor (7)
**23.** Hart following the run to an area of London (7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your style is a little different to what I am used to, but I think:

Across

> 1. **JURY RIG** (JIG contain extreme letters of UnfaiR YoutubeR)
>  2. **YAM BEAN** (anagram of MAYBE AN)
>  3. **EXECUTE** (double definition)
>  4. **JEZEBEL** (first and last letters)
>  5. **QUAKERS** (QUACKER without sixth letter of charaCter and final letter of Chandler'S)
>  6. **USHER IN** (USHER=singer; IN=home)
>  9. **THORIUM** (anagram of THOU MRI)
>  12. **CARDIFF** (Queen is an example of a playing CARD; IFF = if and only if)
>  13. **EARLDOM** (remove initial letters)
>  14. **OAK WOOD** (homophone for OKE WOULD)
>  15. **OPTIMAL** (T+IM inside OPAL)
>  16. **DELAYED** (LAY inside DEED)
>  17. **LIGHTED** (initials of Gentry Have replacing S in LISTED)
>  18. **ITS OVER** (anagram of SOVIET +R)
>  21. **BARBELL** (BRA backwards inside BELL)
>  24. **LADYBUG** (anagram of BUY GLAD)

Down

> 3. **EJECTED** (DEJECTED without first letter)
>  4. **JERICHO** (hidden word)
>  5. **QUIVERY** (QUERY with IVE in place of E)
>  6. **UNIFORM** (UNI=college, FORM=class)
>  7. **RIDDLER** (RIDER around DL)
>  8. **FIRE-DOG** (I RED inside FOG)
>  10. **OLMSTED** (anagram of SOLD MET)
>  11. **MIKOLAS** (anagram of MAIL'S OK)
>  15. **OCTOBER** (anagram of REBOOT around C)
>  16. **DEVALUE** (EU + LAVED reversed)
>  17. **LUBE JOB** (every fifth letter of WE AT LUG-A-NUT...)
>  18. **I SEE YOU** (homophone of ICU)
>  19. **DENIZEN** (ZINE reversed inside DEN)
>  20. **GORILLA** (anagram of ALLIGATOR less A and T)
>  22. **REGRESS** (EGRESS after R)
>  23. **LAMBETH** (LAM=run BETH=hart)

> [image]

A particular tip of the hat for using a [p1 wallpaper symmetric grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group#Group_p1_(o)).